# Finding complex roots of quadratic equation to the power of 3

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

**Here's the problem:**

Find the 6 complex numbers solutions of the equation $(x^2+x+1)^3=8i$, presenting your solutions in exponential form

I'm acquainted with solving complex roots of quadratic equations, but not one with exponents.

Here is my working so far: I'm not sure if I am approaching this question right

$(x^2+x+1)^3 = 8i$

$(x^2+x+1) = 2e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{2ki\pi}{3}}$

$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2+\frac{3}{4}=2e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{2ki\pi}{3}}$

$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2=2e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{2ki\pi}{3}}-\frac{3}{4}$

$x+\frac{1}{2}= \sqrt{2e^{\frac{i\pi}{6}+\frac{2ki\pi}{3}}-\frac{3}{4}}$

Comment: I think what you have done is right. Please just make sure you consider both the square roots in the last step.

Answer (score 1):

As $8i=(-2i)^3$

$$\left(\dfrac{x^2+x+1}{-2i}\right)^3=1$$

$\implies \dfrac{x^2+x+1}{-2i}=w$  where $w$ is a cube root of unity

$\iff x^2+x+1+2iw=0$

Answer (score 0):

The number $8i$ is equal to $2^3e^{\pi i/2}$. Therefore, its cubic roots are $2e^{\pi i/6}$, $2e^{5\pi i/6}$, and $2e^{3\pi i/2}(=-2i)$. So, solve the equations $x^2+x+1=\omega$, for each $\omega\in\left\{2e^{\pi i/6},2e^{5\pi i/6},-i\right\}$.